# Looking for browser notifications that include user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, notifications

I have looked for a while but found nothing that meets my demands. I am looking for something similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aze4E.png) in terms of size and simplicity.
However, I would like the notification to also include a input box for the user to insert text (similar to a form) in a way that it ables communication with the webpage using that input. Using the previous image... [ideia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avz9D.png). Would be better if worked well in all browsers.

Can someone help me with this? I am using javascript.
Thank you.

Comment: you can use this link for desktop notification https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications but you cannot put the textbox in it

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya Yeah I really need the input part...

Comment: You can use another notification for user input text box but you cannot do it with desktop notification